# Bootstrap mobile dropdown offcanvas navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with the navbar width on mobile views: for phones it cannot be more than approx. 240px but I have some very long menu names. I need a padding-right and of course a line-break.

Here's my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tinusmile/dnq8jhbu/33/

```html
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Submenu #1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">A too long submenu name for the width of the navbar</a></li>
</ul>`
```

Answer (score 2):

To just make it fit you could use ellipsis. This will show 3 dots when the text will become too long.

```
.dropdown-menu li a {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 220px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or just wrap the words like this:

```
.dropdown-menu li a {
    word-break: break-word;
    // this is required in your fiddle because it is now setting 
    // the white-space: nowrap; You could just remove that.
    white-space: normal;
}
```